# Passing user inputted start and end date values into sql query that generates a dataframe

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to have a start and end date as variables in a long SQL query in python that generates a dataframe. I've gone through the other posts regarding this and tried everything I know but I get errors and none of them work. I've shortened the sql query to show just the relevant part. Can anyone please give me any suggestions? I think the issue might have to do with the format of the date.

```
def get_dataframe():
    startdate = 'input_startdate'
    enddate = 'input_enddate'

    query="""
                    where date between ? and ?
        """
    params={'start':startdate, 'end':enddate}
    conn = db.msSQLConnect()
    df = pd.read_sql(query,conn,params)

    return df
```

Comment: " I think the issue might have to do with the format of the date" well we can't possibly tell because you haven't shown either of the relevant parameters in a datetime format, the error, or the whole query to ensure it's valid SQL. Please include an [mcve].

Comment: Apologies, I'm a new user and I'll keep that in mind. I've tested the sql query with values such as '2019-01-01' for start and '2019-02-01' for end so I know the query works with hard coded dates. input_startdate is a global variable and should be in the same format as the dates that I just specified. the error with this code is that pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant information. A traceback is helpful too, not just the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove quotes around `startdate` and `enddate` variable assignments.
With quotes literal string 'input_startdate' and 'input_enddate' are passed to the query, instead of the date values of the variables.

```
startdate = input_startdate
enddate = input_enddate
```